# How does bash array slicing work when start index is not provided?

Tags: arrays, bash, scripting

I'm looking at a script, and I'm having trouble determining what is going on.

Here is an example:

```
# Command to get the last 4 occurrences of a pattern in a file
lsCommand="ls /my/directory | grep -i my_pattern | tail -4"

# Load the results of that command into an array
dirArray=($(echo $(eval $lsCommand) | tr ' ' '\n'))

# What is this doing?
yesterdaysFileArray=($(echo ${x[@]::$((${#x[@]} / 2))} | tr ' ' '\n'))
```

There is a lot going on here.  I understand how arrays work, but I don't know how $x is getting referenced if it was never declared.

I see that the $((${#x[@]} / 2}} is taking the number of elements and dividing it in half, and the tr is used to create the array.  But what else is going on?

Comment: This is horrifying! Where did you get this script from? That's a wonderful example of what you shouldn't do! exercise: find all the antipatterns.

Comment: Hah!  I aim to please.  Just an old script I discovered while working.  Any clue on what that last line is trying to do?

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: You could drop the `tr` command entirely; the unquoted command substitution is subject to work-splitting, which treats newlines and spaces the same. In fact, relying on word-splitting is both fragile and, in this case, unnecessary. `yesterdaysFileArray=( "${x[@]::$((${#x[@]}/2}" )` would produce the same result.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann `lsCommand` is shown, there is no `x` set anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help.  I didn't write this code, or else I would've known what it was doing.  I just happened to stumble upon it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the last line is an array slice pattern in `bash` of form `${array[@]:1:2}`, where `array[@]` returns the contents of the array, `:1:2` takes a slice of length 2, starting at index `1`.

So for your case though you are taking the start index *empty* because you haven't specified any and length as half the count of array.

But there is a lot better way to do this in `bash` as below. Don't use `eval` and use the built-in globbing support from the shell itself

```
cd /my/directory 
fileArray=()
for file in *my_pattern*; do
    [[ -f "$file" ]] || { printf '%s\n' 'no file found'; return 1; }
    fileArray+=( "$file" )
done
```

and do

```
printf '%s\n' "${fileArray[@]::${#fileArray[@]}/2}"
```

Comment: This makes really good sense.  So it is essentially trying to get the first half of the elements inside of ${x}.  I was thinking 'slice' due to the ::, but I wasn't 100% sure.  Thanks a lot for the information and the code on how to improve it.